# Excel: Get nth occurrence with multiple criteria (INDEX/MATCH)

Tags: excel

I would like a formula to find the second occurrence of column A with "c" and "n" in columns B and C respectively.

```
A   B   C
1   a   m
2   b   n
3   c   m
4   a   p
5   b   m
6   c   n
7   a   m
8   b   p
9   c   n
```

The solution is: 9.

So far, I know how to get the nth occurence with one criteria:
`=INDEX(A2:A10;SMALL(IF(C2:C10="n";ROW(C2:C10)-ROW(INDEX(C2:C10;1;1))+1);2))`

Comment: Just add a further IF clause to your existing formula to that effect.

Comment: Hi XOR LX, I have already tried but I guess I am missing something on the way. Would you mind to show me how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=INDEX(A2:A10;SMALL(IF(B2:B10="c";IF(C2:C10="n";ROW(C2:C10)-ROW(INDEX(C2:C10;1;1))+1));2))`

Regards

Comment: I had the same formula so it made me realize I forgot to convert into array. Thanks!