# Returning multiple string values using index,match on multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, formula

I have a google form populating an ever-growing spreadsheet from which I would like to generate an overview sheet as a daily report.

Here is an excerpt from "Form Responses 1"

[image: https://pasteboard.co/I74RboO.png]

I am successfully using an index/match (matching on both the property name (col C) and yesterday's date (col F)) to return a string value (Col H) but I am struggling to return more than one instance of a match EG: rows 416 / 417.

As the result is a string, all the tutorials I can find (which use small()) don't appear to work. I am relatively new to excel so may be missing something.

everything I have tried which is mainly small() give me a #num! error so I am guessing that small is the wrong way to go, but cannot google up an alternative.

Formula I am trying is

Formula in  E4:

```
{=INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$H:$H,SMALL(MATCH(1,($E$3='Form Responses 1'!$F:$F)*($B$4='Form Responses 1'!$C:$C),0),ROW(1:1)))}
```

Formula in E5:

```
{=INDEX('Form Responses 1'!$H:$H,SMALL(MATCH(1,($E$3='Form Responses 1'!$F:$F)*($B$4='Form Responses 1'!$C:$C),0),ROW(2:2)))}
```

Which works on the first instance (row 4) but not row 5:

[image: https://pasteboard.co/I74WbYE.png]

There may be up to 5 or so rows for the 2 matches (historically) so I need to be able to present these in a readable form.
Currently I am using excel but will need to port to google forms and post out automatically on the daily.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Your `Match` will only be able to store one number, not an array - what you need is a formula like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760533/excel-get-nth-occurrence-with-multiple-criteria-index-match

Comment: Many thanks - will try.

Comment: Sorry I feel useless, but the example listed there gets rejected by excel ("there's a problem with this formula") so I am not able to begin to understand. so I get that I am using the IF statements instead of MATCH but not following the 2 x ROW() parts - are they both just for counting? (for the SMALL)?. thanks

Comment: No worries, we'll get there. Ive made an example below for you to try out - simply replace the arrays and target values with yours and don't forget to `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for you to try out in a simplified way

```
      A     B        C            D        E       F          G
1     CH    Red      999
2     DE    Red      654'321                       Blue
3     FR    Green    43'213                        DE
4     CH    Green    74'123
5     DE    Green    4'651                 1       6'541      645'132
6     SA    Blue     6'541                 2       3'120      135'561
7     CH    Blue     3'120                 3       645'132    #NUM!
8     DE    Blue     645'132               4       148'085    #NUM!
9     CH    Red      179'395               5       141'823    #NUM!
10    DE    Red      173'133               6       135'561    #NUM!
11    SA    Green    166'871                
12    CH    Green    160'609
13    DE    Green    154'347
14    SO    Blue     148'085
15    CH    Blue     141'823
16    DE    Blue     135'561
```

.

Column F: **Single criteria** : Only "Blue"  --> 6 occurences

in F5 I have

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$18,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$18=$F$2,ROW($B$1:$B$18)-ROW(INDEX($B$1:$B$18,1,1))+1),E5))
```

Column G: **Multiple cliteria:** "Blue" & "DE"  --> 2 occurences

in G5 I have

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$18,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$18=$F$2,IF($A$1:$A$18=$F$3, ROW($A$1:$A$18)-ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$18,1,1))+1)),E5))`
```

Careful: those are array formulas -> press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when inputting the formula

in this example, the Nth value is defined by the 1-6 numbers in column E

Comment: this is awesome! - thanks loads for taking the time to help me

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark it as an answer and upvote if it helped solve your issue :)